# why controller var isn't available within a test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm trying to follow Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial in http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out, but with some changes to practice, above all, some variations and the Test::Unit framework. In the tutorial, RSpec is used, while I'm trying to stick to Test::Unit + Shoulda-context.

In chapter 9 I'm suposed to pass some functional tests that use a var called 'controller', but my tests don't work as they find out that 'controller' doesn't exist. This is what I get:

> marcel@pua:~/Desenvolupament/Rails3Examples/ror_tutorial$ rake
>   test:recent Loaded suite
>   /home/marcel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
>   Started F
>   =============================================================================== Failure: test: POST 'create' with valid signin (email and password)
>   should redirect to the user show page. (SessionsControllerTest)
>   [test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb:58]: Expected at least 1
>   element matching "title", found 0.  is not true.
>   =============================================================================== E
>   =============================================================================== Error: test: POST 'create' with valid signin (email and password)
>   should sign in the user. (SessionsControllerTest): NameError:
>   undefined local variable or method `controller' for
>
> ```
> test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <class:SessionsControllerTest>'
> ```
>
> =============================================================================== Finished in 0.957865676 seconds. 7 tests, 6 assertions, 1 failures, 1
>   errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications 0% passed
>   7.31 tests/s, 6.26 assertions/s rake aborted! Command failed with status (1): [/home/marcel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/b...] Tasks: TOP
>   => test:recent (See full trace by running task with --trace)

This is the original (RSpec) test:

```
describe SessionsController do
  ...
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    ...
    describe "with valid email and password" do
      before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
        @attr = { :email => @user.email, :password => @user.password }
      end

      it "should sign the user in" do
        post :create, :session => @attr
        controller.current_user.should == @user
        controller.should be_signed_in
      end

      it "should redirect to the user show page" do
        post :create, :session => @attr
        response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my translated (into Test::Unit + Sholuda-context) test:

```
class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "POST 'create'" do
    context "with valid signin (email and password)" do
      setup do
        @attr = {email: "test@email.tst",  password: "testpwd"}
        @user=User.create! @attr.merge!({name: "test_user", password_confirmation: "testpwd"})
      end

      should "sign in the user" do
        post :create, :session => @attr
        assert_equal @user, controller.current_user
      end

      should "redirect to the user show page" do
        post :create, :session => @attr
        assert_select "title", /Show/
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Has anybody any idea how to make my test work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the official Rails testing guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html, I've seen that an instance variable called @controller is enabled in functional tests. so, the Test::Unit version should be:

```
should "sign in the user" do
  post :create, :session => @attr
  assert_equal @user, @controller.current_user
end
```